# Training data for digit recognition on Android with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, ocr

I'm trying to do digit recognition on Android with OpenCV. I'm using the k-Nearest Neighbor (kNN) functions of OpenCV on samples images I found [on this blog](http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.fr/2012/06/digit-recognition-with-opencv.html) (basically a single `.png` per digit + an image with multiple digits for testing purposes).

I'm running in some issues when I'm trying to create the training data. Here's my code so far :

```
Mat trainData = new Mat();

Mat img = new Mat();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/ocr/" + i + ".png";
    img = Highgui.imread(path);
    img.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    Mat imgResized = preProcessImage(img);

    trainData.push_back(imgResized);
    myint[i] = i;
}

trainResponses.put(0,0,myint);

CvKNearest knn = new CvKNearest();
knn.train(trainData, trainResponses);
```

( `preProcessImage(Mat img)` returns a cropped image in a Mat of a single digit at a time.)

My problem occurs at `trainData.push_back(imgResized);` where I'm essentially trying to push a Mat (imgResized) into another Mat (trainData). I've got an error that leads me to think I'm doing something terribly wrong (push_back is apparently waiting for the 2 Mats to have the same column size, which doesn't make much sense here).

So my question is : **how to create a training data Mat from multiple images ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found why it didn't work. The training images must all be the same size. Now it looks something like this :

```
(...)
imgResized = preProcessImage(img);
Size dsize = new Size(20,30);
Imgproc.resize(imgResized, imgResized, dsize);
imgResized.convertTo(imgResized, CvType.CV_32FC1);
imgResized = imgResized.reshape(1, 1);
train_samples.push_back(imgResized);
(...)
```

I'm pretty sure it needs some refining but at least there's no error thrown now.